# calculating all the permutations of an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, permutation

I am trying to write a method to permute an array into all it's possible permutations. I am taking each array in the form of an ArrayList, flipping two elements, and then returning the ArrayList to an ArrayList of ArrayLists. If I print each array to the screen after flipping the two elements, it is printing as expected. [1,2,3] with the first two elements flipped prints as [2,1,3] but when I add the permuted ArrayList to the other ArrayList, they are all printing out as [1,2,3]

The code:

```
public static void arrays() {
    
    //convert the input Lists to ArrayLists
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    a.add(1);
    a.add(2);
    a.add(3);
    //ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>(B);
    
    //an array with 3 elements will have 1 * 2 * 3 permutations
    Integer numberOfPossiblePermutations = numberOfPermutations(a);
    
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allPermutations = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    allPermutations.add(a);
    
    System.out.println("The properly rearranged arrays");
    while (allPermutations.size() < numberOfPossiblePermutations) {
        //get the last array in the list of arrays
        ArrayList<Integer> lastArray = allPermutations.get(allPermutations.size()-1);
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayToAdd = lastArray;
        
        for (int i=0; i+1<lastArray.size(); i++) {
            //flip two elements in the array
            
            int x = lastArray.get(i);
            int y = lastArray.get(i+1);
            arrayToAdd.set(i+1, x);
            arrayToAdd.set(i, y);
            System.out.println(arrayToAdd);
            allPermutations.add(arrayToAdd);
        }
        
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("but when I add each ArrayList to another ArrayList they are coming out like this");
    
    for (int i=0; i<allPermutations.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(allPermutations.get(i));
    }
    
}

//accepts an array and returns the possible number of permutations
public static Integer numberOfPermutations(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    Integer numberOfPermutations = 1;
    for (int i=1; i<=a.size(); i++) {
        numberOfPermutations *= i;
    }
    return numberOfPermutations;    
}
```

The output:

- The properly rearranged arrays
- [2, 1, 3]
- [2, 3, 1]
- [3, 2, 1]
- [3, 1, 2]
- [1, 3, 2]
- [1, 2, 3]
- but when I add each ArrayList to another ArrayList they are coming out like this
- [1, 2, 3]
- [1, 2, 3]
- [1, 2, 3]
- [1, 2, 3]
- [1, 2, 3]
- [1, 2, 3]
- [1, 2, 3]

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: when I have an ArrayList [a, b, c] and I shuffle two elements [b, a, c] and I add it to an ArrayList of ArrayLists it is going back to [a, b, c] instead of having the two elements I switched in the different order. but when I print the array as is, the elements are switched.

Comment: you are always adding the same ArrayList to result and after that mutating it, try: `ArrayList<Integer> lastArray = new ArrayList(allPermutations.get(allPermutations.size()-1));`

Comment: I don't understand how it is being added before permuting it when I print it right before adding it, it prints the permuted array. 

System.out.println(arrayToAdd);
allPermutations.add(arrayToAdd);

Comment: Have a look at Apache Commons https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#permutations-java.util.Collection- they have this method and you can see the source if you want to know how its implemented.

Comment: I instantiated the arrays inside the for loop instead of the while loop as new ArrayLists, and it's working like I wanted it to.

Comment: I appreciate that this has already been done but part of me doing this is just to do it, but I got stuck and it was starting to become more irritating than interesting, and Java is not my best language.

Answer (score 0):

You are only interacting with a single `ArrayList` instance, but calling it by different names. So when you print it, you're printing it at different stages of that object's lifetime, but it's still the same instance.

This line:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayToAdd = lastArray;
```

does not make a copy of the object; it's just giving the same object a different name. You need to explicitly copy it. For example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayToAdd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arrayToAdd.addAll(lastArray);
```

Comment: Better do this: new ArrayList<Integer>(lastArray);